# Why do my displays settings show up as "laptop" after installing nvidia drivers?

Tags: nvidia

Why does the displays setting in Ubuntu 12.04 show my displays as "laptop" after I have installed the recommended nVidia drivers for my GTX460? Is this normal and my displays need to be set up using the nVidia software?